# Is there a test environment for Twitter's API?

Tags: api, twitter

I'm trying to build a simple, tweet posting, app (or part of my app). I created a developer account on Twitter, I got my keys after creating an app. Now my question is, during development, I want to test what I'm writing, but of course I don't want to post tweets to my account's timeline.

Is there a testing environment where I can see the tweets created during development? I've looked at the docs, found about Twitter Labs but I don't think that's what I need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hello I have been working with this api before and I didnt see sandbox for twitter api , what I do is use a test account created by me.

Comment: that's 1 idea, let's see if someone else has something else to share. I find it strange that Twitter would not provide such thing. During development you don't want devs to post to your account their silly messages: "qwerty12345" :D

Answer (score 0):

There is no test environment. One option would be to post Tweets to a protected Twitter account so that you can still check them via the API, but they will not be shown on the web unless you are the owner (or an approved follower of the owning account).

Comment: that's strange right? Do they expect devs to get it on the first try and push to production right away?